# i want to parse this json data with nodejs but gets error undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

i used this code in nodejs to get data from json but gets error and say undefined

```js
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(myJSON.payload); //output: undefined
```

and i have same error in javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON.payload;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

what is my error? can any one help me...

Comment: The result of `JSON.stringify()` is just a simple string; there's no "payload" property. You can examine `obj.payload` because that makes sense. Once you `.stringify()` it however you just have a string. There's no need to "parse" an object that's declared with an object initializer expression; the object already exists and is ready for use.

Comment: Do you realize what `JSON.stringify(obj)` does? It stringifies the object. It returns a string. If you only need the `payload` property, you don't need to stringify.

Comment: yes i know , i using nodejs i have used obj.payload but not working and gets this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at receivedMessage (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:535:20)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is already object, you can

```
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
console.log(myJSON.payload);
```

to parse string to object use `JSON.parse`

```
var str = '{"payload": "fp_2"}';
var myJSON = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(myJSON.payload);
```

`JSON.stringify` used to convert obejct to string

```
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str);
// {"payload":"fp_2"}
```

Comment: i using nodejs i have used obj.payload but not working and gets this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined at receivedMessage (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:535:20)"

Answer (score 0):

What happens in both your example is you are trying to get property "payload" from a string, which does not have this kind of property.
The method `JSON.stringify()` creates string from any given object, so your custom object with property "payload" was transformed to JS string object, which does not have it anymore.

This is the list of properties, that JS string has:

- constructor
- length
- prototype

You can find definition of each property and read more about strings in JS with this link: [W3 Schools JS string](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

If you want to use "payload" from your custom object, you don't need to `JSON.stringify()` it. Just use it:

```
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
console.log(obj.payload);

// Or in your html example
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.payload;
```

Comment: yes i know , i using nodejs i have used obj.payload but not working and gets this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined at receivedMessage (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:535:20)"

Comment: @PawanOsman can you give example of code, that gives you TypeError obj as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

write this for nodejs

```
var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
console.log(obj.payload);
```

write this for script file

```
<script>

var obj = {payload:'fp_2'};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.payload;

</script>
```

Comment: i using nodejs i have used obj.payload but not working and gets this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined at receivedMessage (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:535:20)"

Comment: This error occurs when you have defined variable, but not give value to it and you are trying to access value.

Comment: but i know that payload variable has a value and equal to "fp_2" i want tt get it but get this error . my json data is from request. i have messenger bot i want to detect quick reply payload . i get that QrPayload variable equal to "{payload:'fp_2'}" but when i use QrPayload.payload get that error